# c# Get Calling Method Without Stack Trace

Tags: c#, .net

I've noticed that .NET 4.5 has a new attribute called **[CallerMemberNameAttribute]** which, when attached to a parameter of a method, will supply the string name of the method that called *that* method (if that makes sense).

However, unfortunately (because I want to make something with XNA) I'm only targeting .NET 4.0.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
void MethodA() {
   MethodB();
}

void MethodB() {
   string callingMethodName = (...?);
   Console.WriteLine(callingMethodName);
}
```

Where my output would be *MethodA*.

I know I could do this via stack trace, but that's a) Unreliable and b) Sloooow...
So I'm wondering if there's any other way to glean that information, however that may be...

I was hoping for any ideas or knowledge that anyone might have on the issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Pass in the calling method name as a string?

Comment: @Oded Well yes clearly I could call MethodB("MethodA") but the point is I'm trying to do it dynamically, so that if I change MethodA to MethodC I don't have to edit that call as well.

Comment: You failed to make that point in the question.

Comment: "Can I have .NET 4.5 features in .NET 4.0?"  Not really.  Not easily.  Stack trace is probably the best dynamic way to do this in .NET 4.0.

Comment: You can apparently use the same trick as we did with the ExtensionAttribute.

Comment: The .Net 4.5 features @TimS. refers to are the Caller Info Attributes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio 2012 to compile this, you can write your own `CallerMemberNameAttribute` and use it the same way you would with .NET 4.5 even if you still target .NET 4.0 or 3.5.  The compiler will still perform the substitution at compile time, even targeting an older framework version.

Just adding the following to your project will do the trick:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    public sealed class CallerMemberNameAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

Comment: I'm only a hobbyist programmer so sorry if this is a stupid question, but is there a way I can see the source for Microsoft's CallerMemberNameAttribute? To copy it, I mean.

Comment: In general, yes, you can decompile .NET libraries using ILSpy.  http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx  However, attributes rarely yield anything interesting, since the interesting bit is more often in how it's used by other code.  E.g. from what @ReedCopsey says, the transformation is done at compile time by the compiler, not by the attribute itself, and you don't even need the .NET 4.5 runtime, so you'll likely see no interesting code.

Comment: Ah, so the compiler just sees the name 'CallerMemberNameAttribute' and inserts its own logic? If so, I can just create a blank attribute with that name and it'll work?

Comment: Oh my god, magic! Are you a wizard? I want to read more about this magic of compiler substitution even when targeting older framework, what's the correct term for this?

Comment: @user1249190 I don't know of this being published anywhere - it's just something that I tried and which works ;)  Since it's a compiler feature, in general, the compiler doesn't care which framework you're using - it looks for the patterns in order to implement features.

Answer (score 0):

You could supply the caller name as a parameter to the called method. Not quite what you’re asking for, but it works without needing to access the stack frame:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
void MethodA() 
{
    string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
    MethodB(methodName);
}

void MethodB(string callingMethodName) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(callingMethodName);
}
```

By using `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`, you can ensure that your implementation remains refactor-safe – if the name of your method changes, the results would still be correct.

Don’t forget to mark your calling method with `MethodImplOptions.NoInlining` so as to avoid method inlining.